# Any way to add Google Maps in Flutter for Web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, google-maps-flutter

I am exploring flutter-web and want to add google map in it. Although, I have used google map using google_maps_flutter in flutter-app but that works for Android and iOS.

Comment: I posted a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57488553/3268303

Comment: This solution is easier: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57746754/3268303

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use the Google Maps library with Flutter Web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57155881/how-to-use-the-google-maps-library-with-flutter-web)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A new official plugin has been released recently: https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter_web . It already works with the existing google_maps_flutter plugin, just add your api script in the `web/index.html` . Do take note its limitations for now -  no rotation, no map toolbar, no my location function.

Comment: Is there any way to get the same api for all supported platforms - web, android, ios? Separate plugin for web is against multiplatform functionality promised by Flutter. If I want web only, I don't need Flutter for that

Comment: @user1209216 As of now it's not yet endorsed to the google maps plugin so it needs the dependency. [Check readme.](https://github.com/ditman/plugins/tree/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter_web) Though I haven't tried it myself, maybe you can try to use a webview.

Comment: Is it safe to add the google maps api key in the header of the index.html file?

Comment: @AlienDecoy You have to restrict the key for your domain in the Google Cloud API Credential settings.

Comment: @user1209216 You can share a key between the platforms, but then you cannot restrict it. You actually want to use 3 keys (Android, iOS, web) so you can restrict each of them to their platform and app fingerprint / domain.

Comment: I'm seeing a "TargetPlatform.macOS is not yet supported by the Maps Plugin" error when using that package. The debug instance works fine, however, when I build and deploy the web app, the error is displayed. Considering raising a bug.

Answer (score 23):

First, you need the Google Map api keys. Before initializing, you have to have a project in your Google Cloud Platform. Create one if you don't have one.

[image]

Next, search for "Javascript Map" and enable it. Otherwise, the api key will shout an error that says the google map service is not activated.

[image]

Initialize the google map js sdk in our `index.html` file located inside `web` folder of your project tree.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<YOUR-API-KEY>"></script>
```

And import [google_maps](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps) in `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
dependencies:
  google_maps: ^3.4.1
```

And here is how you create a google map widget.

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps/google_maps.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

Widget getMap() {
  String htmlId = "7";

  // ignore: undefined_prefixed_name
  ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(htmlId, (int viewId) {
    final myLatlng = LatLng(1.3521, 103.8198);

    final mapOptions = MapOptions()
      ..zoom = 10
      ..center = LatLng(1.3521, 103.8198);

    final elem = DivElement()
      ..id = htmlId
      ..style.width = "100%"
      ..style.height = "100%"
      ..style.border = 'none';

    final map = GMap(elem, mapOptions);

    Marker(MarkerOptions()
      ..position = myLatlng
      ..map = map
      ..title = 'Hello World!'
      );

    return elem;
  });

  return HtmlElementView(viewType: htmlId);
}
```

`htmlId` - a unique id to name the div element

`ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory` - creates a webview in dart

`LatLng(1.3521, 103.8198)` - class that takes latitude and longitude of a location

`DivElement()` - class to create a dive element

`GMap` - creates a google map element

`Marker()` - the red icon that shows in your LatLng in google map

`HtmlElementView()` - creates a platform view for Flutter Web

More about google_maps package found here :

https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps

A quick tutorial on how to use it found here :

https://dev.to/happyharis/flutter-web-google-maps-381a

Hope this helps. Thanks

Comment: A "For developer purpose only" watermark appears on the map, is there any way to remove it?

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tested it yet but if you want a cross-platform solution maybe you can give this a shot: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_google_maps

Its description says:

```
A Flutter plugin for integrating Google Maps in iOS, Android and Web applications. It is a wrapper of google_maps_flutter for Mobile and google_maps for Web.
```