# Cannot integrade google-maps into flutter, plugin not loading

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I am trying to follow the "Adding Google Maps to a Flutter app" tutorial from link:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/google-maps-in-flutter#3

After running the code in Android Studio (on MAC) I get the following:

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following JSNoSuchMethodError was thrown building GoogleMap(dirty, dependencies: [Directionality], state: _GoogleMapState#1c76c):
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'maps')
```

Check the screenshot of how it appears in chrome.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this basic Map code, hope you understand and if you have any doubts please feel free to ask in the comments section.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Maps',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MapView(),
    );
  }
}

class MapView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MapViewState createState() => _MapViewState();
}

class _MapViewState extends State<MapView> {
  CameraPosition _initialLocation = CameraPosition(target: LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962),zoom: 14.4746);
  GoogleMapController mapController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Container(
      height: height,
      width: width,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            GoogleMap(
              initialCameraPosition: _initialLocation,
              myLocationEnabled: true,
              myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
              mapType: MapType.normal,
              zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
              zoomControlsEnabled: false,
              onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
              mapController = controller;
                 },
             ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Still tried your basic code but the same error appears:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'maps')
See also: https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/errors

Comment: If I run the initial code or your suggestion on sdk phone emulator (added an android) it works properly. It doesn't work when I run it at Chrome (web). Any idea? Running on web is much faster so it is more preferable for debugging. Thanks

Comment: I think Google Map that you are using may not support the web (I am not sure). If you want to enable a map for the web, [try this article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-web-and-google-maps-f2489b483a1f). but if you want it only for testing I will suggest you use physical mobile.

Answer (score 2):

I have worked with google maps for Flutter web for many different projects, and each time I learn something new. This particular error was driving me nuts, till I found that I forgot to **include the Google Map API in the index.html** inside the project web folder. you may have overlooked it just like me.
please refer to [this topic in the forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57201412/any-way-to-add-google-maps-in-flutter-for-web) to know how to add that.

Answer (score 0):

The last comment above that the web version is not supported was the problem. Tried with the mobile emulator and everything worked right.
Thanks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).