# how to implement google map on flutter web project

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps

I want to implement the google map using flutter web. I need current plug in an details documentations.

Answer (score -1):

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57201412/any-way-to-add-google-maps-in-flutter-for-web][Here is a link.
might help.]

If you are using the google map broadly in the app, you must have a credit card with credits and you have to give the details of the credit card before implementing map in map. You will get a api key after registering with the credit card and need the api key to implement the map in application.

Comment: if you know the question as already asked.. you can flag the question as a duplicate and share the link in a comment section.