# How to add map and markers to flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

How to add a map to flutter google? I get markers from Firestore but now I don't know which map use to flutter web. Most work only on ios/android.

I tried to use flutter_map. But this solution drops me this error.

> 'NetworkImageWithRetry.load' has fewer positional arguments than those of overridden method
>   'ImageProvider.load'.
>
> ImageStreamCompleter load(NetworkImageWithRetry key) {
>                          ^
>   org-dartlang-app:///packages/flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart: Context: This is the overridden
>   method ('load').
>   AssetNotFoundException: flutter_image|lib/network.ddc.dill
>   Error compiling dartdevc module:flutter_image|lib/network.ddc.js
>
> packages/flutter_image/network.dart:73:24: Error: The method 'NetworkImageWithRetry.load' has fewer
>   positional arguments than those of overridden method 'ImageProvider.load'.
>     ImageStreamCompleter load(NetworkImageWithRetry key) {
>                          ^
>   packages/flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart: Context: This is the overridden method ('load').
>
> AssetNotFoundException: flutter_image|lib/network.ddc.dill
>
> AssetNotFoundException: flutter_image|lib/network.ddc.dill
>
> BuildStepCompletedException: Attempt to use a BuildStep after is has completed

**Snapshot**

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new FlutterMap(
  options: new MapOptions(
    center: new LatLng(51.5, -0.09),
    zoom: 13.0,
  ),
  layers: [
    new TileLayerOptions(
      urlTemplate: "https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/"
          "{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x.png?access_token={accessToken}",
      additionalOptions: {
        'accessToken': '<key>',
        'id': 'mapbox.streets',
      },
    ),
    new MarkerLayerOptions(
      markers: [
        new Marker(
          width: 80.0,
          height: 80.0,
          point: new LatLng(51.5, -0.09),
          builder: (ctx) =>
          new Container(
            child: new FlutterLogo(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
}
```

Comment: Can you add more information? what you need to develop and what you have tried. Because current error is ** AssetNotFoundException** assest not found. I am using above-mentioned library and its working fine.

Comment: @Sunny I just want use this library in flutter web. I want to show map in website.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57155881/which-map-solution-package-to-use-with-flutter-web

Answer (score 0):

try change this

```
urlTemplate: "https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/"
      "{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x.png?access_token={accessToken}",
```

strong text

```
urlTemplate: "https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x.png?access_token={accessToken}",
```

Comment: and try add "$" before {}

${id}

Comment: This does not answer the question, as far as I can tell you simply misunderstood string concatenation:
`void main() { print('a' 'b'); }`
This will print "ab".